# Command Line function return True if a port or ports are being used

Tags: shell, networking, command-line, port

I am trying to write a function on to a true or false value if the port is being used. I know how to check if the port is occupied in the terminal using 'lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN'.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

npm install

function setPort() {

 //if port is being used
   //use port + 1

}

setPort
```

What I want to achieve is a function that runs in the command line to check if port is being used if port is being occupied find a port that is free.

Please help.

Comment: You can just use `nc -z localhost 1234` which will try to connect and return sucess if the port is open, or failure if the port is closed

Comment: `lsof -i -P -n | grep 'ESTABLISHED'` ?

Comment: Hey @thatotherguy I am getting this 
     line 11: [nc: command not found 

My code
function setPort() {

  if [nc -z localhost 8080]
  then
    echo true
  else
    echo false
  fi


}

Comment: @john1024 It wasn't returning any value. Any other way?

Comment: Thanks guys! I removed [] in the statement and it worked.